# Systemd stop/disable all templated services that don't match a variable

Tags: systemd

How can I programmatically stop/disable all templated systemd services which don't match a specific variable? For example, I am running `myservice@v1` and I want to stop/disable services which match `myservice@*` *except* for `myservice@v1`.

This is the closest I've come, but `list-units` is giving output that is clearly not meant to be parsed by a machine, making it fragile:

```
export SERVICES="$(systemctl list-units myservice@* --all | \
                   grep myservice | grep -v "@v1" | cut -f1 -d' ')"
if [ -n "$SERVICES" ]; then 
  /bin/systemctl stop $SERVICES
  /bin/systemctl disable $SERVICES
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `--no-legend` to the `systemctl` command to cut out some of the useless junk you don't need. It will then list only the units, with no header or footer.

I also suggest you tighten up your `grep`. As it stands, it will match on `v10` as well as `v1`, just for instance. You could do this by adding `-w` for a word match, or by matching more specifically, e.g. on `@v1.service`

Comment: It also gets rid of the little optional bullet points on the left which is a huge help!

Comment: But wait, there's more!